# Turn list of tuples into binary tensors?

Tags: pytorch

I have a list of tuples in the form below. A given tuple represents a given pair of movies that a given user liked. All tuples, together, capture every combination of movie likes found in my data.

```py
[(movie_a,movie_b),...(movie_a,movie_b)]
```

My task is to create movie embeddings, similar to word embeddings. The idea is to train a single hidden layer NN to predict the most likely movie which any user might like, given a movie supplied. Much like word embeddings, the task is inconsequential; it's the weight matrix I'm after, which maps movies to vectors.

Reference: https://arxiv.org/vc/arxiv/papers/1603/1603.04259v2.pdf

In total, there are 19,000,000 tuples (training examples.) Likewise, there are 9,000 unique movie IDs in my data. My initial goal was to create an input variable, X where each row represented a unique movie_id, and each column represented a unique observation. In any given column, only one cell would be set to 1, with all other values set to 0.

As an intermediate step, I tried creating a matrix of zeros of the right dimensions

```py
X = np.zeros([9000,19000000])
```

Understandably, my computer crashed, simply trying to allocate sufficient memory to X.

Is there a memory efficient way to pass my list of values into PyTorch, such that a binary vector is created for every training example?

Likewise, I tried randomly sampling 500,000 observations. But similarly, passing 9000,500000 to np.zeroes() resulted in another crash.

My university has a GPU server available, and that's my next stop. But I'd like to know if there's a memory efficient way that I should be doing this, especially since I'll be using shared resources.

Comment: After a cursory skim of the paper and it looks like the Skip-Gram maximization is equivalent to [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) objective in pytorch which takes in a list of integers as targets rather than the one-hot encodings. That way you only need to store a list of 19,000,000 as integers (between 0 and 8999).

Comment: I’m so new to PyTorch, thanks for not blasting me. So likewise, can I also send the input as a list of integers rather than trying to make 19 million one hot vectors? (If you happen to know)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly you want. Maybe you could get an example implementation with a subset of the movie_ids working which does into memory, then you could update your question with a working, memory inefficient example. It makes a lot more sense to optimize working code then to pre-optimize, especially since we don't know your implementation details.